How can a RASA bot determine timezone of the user it is interacting with?

I am working on a RASA bot which has user presence throughout the world.
Hence, it is crucial for me to determine what timezone he/she is in, and depending on that the bot will be extracting information applicable to that timezone.

A lame way to do that is.
I can ask the user to choose from a list of timezones and save it in the slot which inturn will save that user information to the db and then that could be re utilized whenever the user is back through actions.

But a better way of addressing this is detecting where the user is geologically positioned, by IP addresses or some webservice call that am currently unaware of.
Does RASA or python have an answer to this?
How do large websites like Amazon/Facebook/Youtube know where the user is located without any specific input?


You can quickly fetch the user's current latitude and longitude using basic JavaScript on the client side. After collecting this data from the front-end, you can then pass the location to Rasa through request metadata.
Check this link: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

@BennisonJ I plan to introduce the bot through slack so not sure how would I be able to put this idea through, but thank you thats one way to get it if I were to use a webpage

Most use third-party services like Maxmind, or receive the location data as part of their edge traffic solution, like Cloudflare. Either way, it's all based on IP address of the incoming request.

That would be a cost related solution, am keen to know if I could really try my hands on including something that would be light and easy to go on in through RASA itself.
